# Google Docs - script to set table row attributes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

How do I set these table row attributes in Google Docs with GAS?

1. First row: Pin as header row as below:
2. All rows: Disable 'Allow row to overflow across pages' as shown below:

[image: screenshot of Table properties showing row attributes]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution:

This can be done with [Docs API](https://developers.google.com/docs/api), which can be used in Apps Script through [Advanced Docs Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/docs) (which you'll have to [enable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services)).

The two requests you are interested in are [PinTableHeaderRowsRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#PinTableHeaderRowsRequest) and [UpdateTableRowStyleRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#updatetablerowstylerequest), both of which are part of method [documents.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate).

Both these requests require you to provide the index in the document where the table starts. To get this information, you should call [documents.get](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/get) and find the structural elements in the body that have a `table` property.

#### Code sample:

For example, if you wanted to update the first table in your document to pin the first two rows and prevent rows to overflow, you could do the following:

```
const TABLE_INDEX = 0; // 0-based index of the table you want to update (for example, if you want to update the first table in your document body, this would be 0)
const NUM_PINNED_ROWS = 2; // Number of rows to pin 
const PREVENT_OVERFLOW = true; // Whether to allow row to overflow across pages or not

function updateTable() {
  let currentTableIndex = 0;
  let index;
  let i = 0;
  const documentId = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId();
  const document = Docs.Documents.get(documentId);
  const { content } = document.body;
  while (typeof index === 'undefined' && i < content.length) { // Loop through body content until your table is found
    const element = content[i];
    const { table } = element;
    if (table) { // Check current element is table
      if (TABLE_INDEX === currentTableIndex) {
        index = element.startIndex; // If it's the correct index table, end iteration
      } else {
        currentTableIndex++;
      }      
    }
    i++;
  }
  if (typeof index !== 'undefined') { // Check the desired table was found
    const resource = {
      "requests": [
        {
          "pinTableHeaderRows": { // Set pinned rows
            "tableStartLocation": {
              //"segmentId": string, // Uncomment if table is not in doc's body
              "index": index
            },
            "pinnedHeaderRowsCount": NUM_PINNED_ROWS
          }
        },
        {
          "updateTableRowStyle": { // Set row overflow
            "tableStartLocation": {
              //"segmentId": string, // Uncomment if table is not in doc's body
              "index": index
            },
            "tableRowStyle": {
              "preventOverflow": PREVENT_OVERFLOW
            },
            "fields": "preventOverflow"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
    Docs.Documents.batchUpdate(resource, documentId);
  }
}
```

Comment: Oddly enough, the script has no effect when I apply it to a table I'm appending with Google Sheets data. There are are existing tables in the doc and when I pass the index of one of these tables, the attributes are set correctly, but when I pass the index of the appended table, nothing happens. No exception, just nothing - any idea why that may be?

Comment: @nquirer If you are adding the table and modifying it using the same script, you might have to use saveAndClose https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#saveAndClose() to make sure the table is actually added to the document before updating it.

Comment: Ah yes, works perfectly! And it makes perfect sense but I would not have thought of that. Actually thought it may be a timing issue - was going to try Utilities.sleep(). lamblichus, this has been a great help - do you have a donation page?